# "Local" use of \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

Tags: fonts

Using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` facilitates the use of bold small caps, but it comes with the disadvantage of blurry text. Is it possible to use *those* bold small caps (as opposed to say those resulting from e.g. the use of `\usepackage{bold-extra}`) locally, say in chapter headings, without getting any of the global effects of `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
This text is blurry

\textbf{\scshape\huge But at least this text is bold small caps suitable for a heading}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: _Off-topic:_ You should have a `\par` after `heading` to correct the line spacing.

Comment: It is not blurry for me. Did you install cm-super?

Comment: the main advantage of T1 is not bold small caps it is correct hyphenation of accented words (less of an issue in English) if you get blurry text then your local font setup is incomplete.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks, installing cm-super did the trick! (The blurriness is subtle and may have been lost in the process of taking a screen capture to convert into a picture. But it made a clear difference for full pages of text.)

Comment: @David Carlisle My current problem has been solved, but I am nevertheless curious: Why did my recent standard installation of MiKTeX give me an incomplete local font setup? Do I need to make a note to my future self that I need to make this manual change every time I install MiKTeX?

Comment: You might consider using the `fontspec` package in XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, rather than `fontenc`. That will give you modern OpenType fonts.

Comment: cm-super is a quite large package and the basic variant miktex doesn't install it by default, so yes if you again install a basic miktex you will have to add again (as you will probably have to install other missing packages too). The easiest is -- if you have enough space -- to install everything.